# curl post data key:val pair from file

Tags: php, ajax, http, rest, curl

I was wondering if it is possible to do a curl through the command line by posting json data using regular strings as well as data from file

I tried,

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: applicaton/json" -d '{"port":"10001", "nodeID": "testnode", "ca": '"`cat cert.pem`"'}' http://localhost:1215/net/tunnel
```

But that says an error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

Is the approach incorrect or do I have a bug?

Update:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/user/work/derivation/keys# curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: applicaton/json" -d "{\"port\":\"10001\", \"nodeID\": \"testnode\", \"ca\": \"<tilde>cat cert.pem<tilde>\"}" http://localhost:1215/net/tunnel
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 

at Object.parse (native)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/user/work/boomerang/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/json.js:76:27)
at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
at _stream_readable.js:920:16
at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:459:13)root@ubuntu:/home/user/work/derivation/keys#
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, using the `-d @filename.txt`:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: applicaton/json" -d @filename.txt http://localhost:1215/net/tunnel
```

But your current command should also work. Try this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: applicaton/json" -d "{\"port\":\"10001\", \"nodeID\": \"testnode\", \"ca\": \"'cat cert.pem'\"}" http://localhost:1215/net/tunnel
```

Comment: @waka-waka-waka make sure your json is in correct format and valid one.

Comment: 'cat cert.pem' -> takes as a string obv, so I changed it to <tilde>cat cert.pem<tilde> # SyntaxError: Unexpected token